# Faster way to type control flow statements (in C and php etc)?

Tags: vim

I am new to Vim and I need to speed up my typing for this kind of statements.

```
if (a == 'e') {
   foo();
}
```

In other text editors, I usually type `if() {}` first and then insert the text in to the parenthesis and curly braces. If I do this in Vim, I need to switch back to normal, move cursor to middle of `()` then middle of `{}`... switch between `i` and `esc` ...

What is your suggestion on typing this kind of syntax for Vim beginner? I would be grateful if you can show me the commands for that example step by step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my answer in case you want to go with vanilla Vim.

In the majority of the cases I guess there is no point in entering the parentheses first and filling in the condition later, just type it all in right away:

```
if (a == 'e')
```

Then you can either continue

- by typing `{}<ESC>`:

  ```
  if (a == 'e') {}
                 ^ cursor is here
  ```

  The cursor is already placed so you can continue with `i<CR>` and type the body (if properly configured, Vim should indent for you).
- or by typing `{<CR>}<ESC>`:

  ```
  if (a == 'e') {
  }
  ^ cursor is here
  ```

  Then you can enter the body by pressing `O` (open new line above cursor). Possibly Vim also automatically indents here (it doesn't in my configuration).

If you really want to fill in the condition after you have entered this:

```
if () {
}
^ cursor
```

you can do so by typing `kf(a`.

---

If anybody knows better ways to do this without plugins, suggestions are welcome.

Comment: We known better ways. They first resulted in abbreviations. Then, with vim6 the abbreviations moved to ftplugins. And along the way the abbreviations became more and more complex to support contexts and many more things. And as we make them available (on vim.org or elsewhere), well they are now labelled "plugins", or "suites".

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for snippet expansion. Take a look at [SnipMate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) or [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*snippets* are like the built-in `:abbreviate` on steroids, usually with parameter insertions, mirroring, and multiple stops inside them. One of the first, very famous (and still widely used) Vim plugins is [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) (inspired by the *TextMate* editor); unfortunately, it's not maintained any more; though there is [a fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate). A modern alternative (that requires Python though) is [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715). There are more, see [this list on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Automated_Text_Insertion).

There are three things to evaluate: First, the features of the snippet engine itself, second, the quality and breadth of snippets provided by the author or others; third, how easy it is to add new snippets.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches that solves your goal:

- abbreviations
- and snippets engines

Abbreviations and the old way of doing things. You just type `if` and space, and tada! You'll find plenty examples around the web. Only a few will be context-sensitive (i.e. they won't expand within comment or string contexts), or able to take the current project spacing style into consideration. In [lh-cpp](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp#code-snippets), you'll find the usual control-statement abbreviations for C and C++, they'll need to be duplicated for similar languages (a `runtime ftplugin/c/c_snippets.vim` from a php ftplugin should do it in your case)-- in [lh-misc](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-misc) I support a couple of others languages (for VimL and shell)

Snippet engines are the trendy way of doing the same thing. This time, you will be able to type `i` or `if` and then `<tab>` (or `CTRL+SPACE`, or ...). Control-statement snippets won't need to be aware of the current context as we need to explicitly require the expansion. Others have already given links to the trendy snippets engines. Snippets from lh-cpp (which relies on mu-template) take the [project style](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-dev#formatting-of-brackets-characters) into account when expanding control-statement snippets (i.e. some projects want `)` and `{` on a same line, other want a newline in between, ...)